# Seeking guidance in driver support 21.04

Tags: drivers, usb, hp, fingerprint-reader

I've been updating to the newest versions of Ubuntu hoping that new usb driver support for my laptops fingerprint reader is implemented, but alas that has yet to happen.  Im only still getting into linux and the vast world that is Informations Tech and these operating systems, and am woefully ignorant when it comes to implementing or developing my own drivers.  Is there a place to request that drivers be developed or created?

No usb driver for fingerprint reader (hp spectre 13 2020)

Below I have attached information regarding my specific device if anyone was curious or anyone ran into similar issues.  I know lack of drivers for some fingerprint readers has been a consistent complaint since fingerprint reader support was implemented.

```
 ~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0408:5440 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP True Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

where `Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc.`  is my fingerprint reader.

So far as I can tell, it does not have support for any linux systems, and i cant determine why.

https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:06cb-00c9

Any suggestions as to who to contact or how to proceed? I'd really love to use the feature, dissapointed that the device I own isn't supported yet.

Comment: It's already reported: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/185